# Доступ к элементам в wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

В футер был добавлен следующий код для попапа:

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="popup_sub">
 <div class="close"></div>
 <form action="http://6thsenseofstyle.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=de7f17faa1d129bd23631fd8f&amp;id=f2be059297" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
     <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <h1 class="popup_title">6th Sense Of Style Newsletter</h1>
      <div class="popup_border"></div>
      <div class="popup_text">
    <p>Sign up to our newsletter to get the latest articles, lookbooks & street style photography direct to your inbox:</p>
   </div>
   <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_de7f17faa1d129bd23631fd8f_f2be059297" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button popup_submit"></div>
     </div>
 </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.popup_sub .close').click(function(){
    $('.popup_sub').hide();
  });
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!$.cookie('subscribed')) {
      $('.popup_sub').show();
      
      $('.popup_sub form').submit(function(){
        $.cookie('subscribed', true, { 
          expires: 365,
          path: '/'
        });
      });
    }
  }, 30000);
</script>
```

В итоге в консоль получаю ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined", то есть на первой же строке кода. Пробовал вывести console.log($('.popup_sub')) - получаю 'undefined'.

Comment: проверьте порядок подключения скриптов. Сначала должен подключаться jQuery, только потом ваш скрипт

Comment: а console.log(jQuery('.popup_sub')) что выдаст?

Comment: выдает 'undefined'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gc8u3q9o/ вот же ваш код, всё прекрасно работает. Вы либо не подключили библиотеку jQuery, либо подключили её неправильно. Выложите полный код страницы либо дайте на неё ссылку

Answer (score 1):

$ is not defined - все ж написано, вы просто не подключили библиотеку jQuery

```
Error{
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
"filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 28,
"colno": 3
}
```

и плюс оберните все что в script в

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

Comment: jquery подключен. Я же говорю, console.log($('.popup_sub')) выводит 'undefined'. То есть скрипт не видит вообще его. doument.ready добавил, провтыкал. Но после его добавления ничего не изменилось